# Crash while trying to build google maps path

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I have a rather urgent problem that I can find no answer to.
I am trying to draw the path between current location and destination using google maps API in an iPhone application. I am getting the data from Google , parse the JSON with no errors , decode the polyline and then I have this method:

```
-(void) loadRouteWithPoints:(NSArray *) routes
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[[routes count]];
    for(int i = 0; i < routes.count; i++)
    {
        CLLocation* loc = (CLLocation*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[routes objectAtIndex:i]];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c;
        c.latitude  = loc.coordinate.latitude;
        c.longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
        coords[i]   = c;
    }

    MKPolyline *line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D*)coords count:[routes count]];
    [self.mapsView addOverlay:line];    
}
```

This throws an exception on `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[routes objectAtIndex:i]];` saying this:

> "-[CLLocation bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

The array that I send as a parameter is the one that I get after decoding the polyline and it's not nil , it has - in my test - 47 values. I can see them and each entry looks like this:

> <+44.47874069,+26.10523033> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/29/12 17:09:37 Eastern European Summer Time

Do you have any idea what might cause this crash and how could it be fixed?

Comment: You have your answer in what you have posted. The exception tells you what the problem is.

Comment: I got that there is no such method/property as "bytes" for a CLLocation. My question is how to solve this. Apparently , it worked for others. So maybe there's something changed in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

the error here indicates that the value you think is in [routes objectAtIndex:x] may not be what you think it is.

try separating out the line, seeing what exactly the class kind is for the object retrieved at [routes objectAtIndex:x] and you'll probably have your answer.

it seems possible that the object is already a CLLocation and doesn't need to be unencoded …

Comment: I am printing the value and it appears to be ok. All the values are like the one posted above - of course , with different coordinates. If I don't call `unarchiveObjectWithData` it works , but the path found is not correct. It has turns and kind of follows streets , but not entirely. Some portions of the path go through parks and lakes , without following a street.